# How to return new array from looping array indexes i and j

Tags: javascript

Given an array of integers and I want to return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target. Assuming that each input would have exactly one solution, and I haven't used the same element twice.

I am using the brute force approach to Loop through each element x and find if there is another value that equals to target−x

**code snippet:**

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
        for(var i ; i<nums.length ; i++){
            for(var j = i + 1; j<nums.length ; j++){
                if (nums[j]==target-nums[i]){
               // This is where I want to return new array 
                    return 
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    };
```

Comment: `for(var i ;` isn't going to work, you need to initialise *i* with a number value: `for(var i=0;`, otherwise you're trying to do `++undefined`. You haven't actually said what the problem is or any errors you get.`++undefined` produces `NaN`, then `++NaN` continues to produce `NaN` so `i<nums.length` is always false (since `NaN < anything` is always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to return the two indices?

```
return [i, j];
```

Comment: May be its an opinionated comment, but I guess this could have been a comment

Comment: is it appropriate if I use `new Array(i,j);`

Comment: Always prefer array literals [] to using the constructor in javascript. Same goes with objects. Use {} instead of new Object()